# How to divide long numeric string into months

Tags: php, regex, string, pattern-matching

I've very long string of numbers

`1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31`

This is the complete list of a year and how can I divide it into months properly.
I don't want to create new one using `PHP` as this `string` has some code `embed` into it at it's backend. once I'm able to divide it, then I can run `xpath queries` on the basis of months
Thanks.

please don't mark it negative, if you don't like it leave it. otherwise stackoverflow will block my account

Comment: How would you do it with pen and paper? It is not much different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`explode()` the string on the spaces, then loop through the array. Check when a number is smaller than the previous one, and start a new month.

Comment: I'll accept your answer after 8 mins as stackoverflow's rule

Comment: Just watch out for double spaces in the string. Deal with them first before you explode.

Comment: yes, sure I'll manage it

Comment: if multiple spaces is an issue use: `$parts = preg_split('/\s+/', $str);`

Comment: @Dagon: Thanks, I just used `str_replace("&nbsp;", "", $days);`
because I space is that, I appended to results with `' '`. and one is with `&nbsp;`
Thanks again.

Comment: @Dagon's solution is very good because it is looking for 1 or more of **any** kind of white space and splitting into an array in one step.

Comment: You could also check whether the value is equal to 1 to start the new month, rather than performing a check on an inequality.

Comment: @adamdc78 even better!